# NLua (LuaInterface) - Calling a function

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface, nlua

How is it possible to call a function when running a lua script using [NLua](https://github.com/NLua) (A LuaInterface fork)?

For example, right now I have:

```
lua.LoadFile("C:\\test.lua")
lua.Call();
```

However, that just runs the script. Inside the script I have a custom function. I want to be able to run that function only. I tried:

```
lua.Call("functionTest")
```

But that didn't work. How can I do that?

My lua script is like so:

```
function functionTest()
   someMethod()
end
```

Or, if it's not possible - Is there a way to include different scripts inside one lua file? I want to be able to run the same file with different arguments for scripts, like:

```
script1 = {
    -- Code
}

script2 = {
    -- Code
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To run a function in Lua you need to first execute the script (the chunk) where the function is implemented.

For instance, if you have a chunk (x.lua)

```
 function MyFunction () 
      print ("MyFunction")
 end function
```

If you use NLua.Lua.LoadFile (which calls [`lua_load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_load)) the compiled code will be on the top of the stack, and you need to run to "declare" the function

The best way to do this is to use `DoFile ()`, `DoFile` will load and run you chunk, and your function will be now "implemented".

To call your Lua function from C# all you gotta do is get the global value with your function name.

```
 lua.DoFile ("x.lua"); // Now MyFunction is declared
 LuaFunction myFunction = lua ["MyFunction"] as LuaFunction;
 myFunction.Call ();
```

Reference: [NLuaBox Source code](https://github.com/codefoco/NLuaBox/blob/master/NLuaBoxAppDelegateInternal.cs#L60)

Hope this can help you.